# Get the value of dropdown list option to display to text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have put the options to a Drop Down list from a database using this code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {pageloaddata.retrievetbldata("Select EmpId, LastName+', '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName AS EmployeeName from Employee");
        DropListEmployeeName.DataSource = pageloaddata.SQLTable;
        DropListEmployeeName.DataTextField = "EmployeeName";
        DropListEmployeeName.DataValueField = "EmpID";
        DropListEmployeeName.DataBind();
        DropListEmployeeName.Items.Insert(0, "Select")
}
```

So the Employee Name's value must be their Employee ID (EmpID)

Now what I want to happen is, if the user have selected an employee, the selectedValue(which is the EmpID) must be displayed into a textbox. Here's the little code I create and doesnt work, It may be very easy to others I know please help a beginner here thank you :)

```
protected void DropListEmployeeName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string empSelected = DropListEmployeeName.SelectedValue.ToString();
    employID.Text = empSelected;
}
```

Note: the EmpID in the database is actually an int, does it matter if I call it as string? If yes please suggest the best code

Comment: what you meant by not working?

Comment: put break point at this line `string empSelected = DropListEmployeeName.SelectedValue.ToString();` and inspect what value you got there. Was it an empty string?

Comment: @woodykiddy i think it's suppose to get the value of the Selected option from the drop down list and put it into the variable: empSelected. For example I selected wolfQueen in the list and has a value of 123.the 123 should be displayed now to employID which is the textbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Jquery to capture the value of your DropDown when it change take a look at this example I made [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/1tqk3o07/) or run the code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#SelectId").change(function () {
      
      var selectObj = $(this);
      
      $("#inputID").val(selectObj.val());
   
   });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<select name="mySelect" id="SelectId">
  <option value="FirstOption">First Option</option>
  <option value="SecondOption">Second Option</option>
  <option value="ThirdOption">Third Option</option>
  <option value="FourthOption">Fourth Option</option>
</select>

<input id="inputID" type="text" name="sampleText" />

</body>

</html>
```

But if you really want to use the Postback method from your DropDown control try this one.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropListEmployeeName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropListEmployeeName_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your dropdown AutoPostBack="True" property.

```
string empSelected =  Convert.Tostring(DropListEmployeeName.SelectedItem.Value);
```

other way

```
var empSelected = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        string semSelected = selectedValue;
```